# How to push a new value to an existing key? Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, key

How can I push a new value to semester? Thanks a lot for the help.

```
var students = {
   "name":"John", "semester":30
   "name":"Anna", "semester":12

}

Wanted output:

var students {
   "name":"John", "semester":30,8
   "name":"Anna", "semester":12,4

}
```

Comment: Is semester an `Array`, or are you actually wanting to join the values together in a string?

Comment: I don't think your `Object` is going to handle data the way you want; `name: "John"` and `semester: 30` aren't link in any way, but your formatting suggests you think they would be - You're also missing an `=`, so it should be `var students = {`

Comment: at the moment semester is an integer, therefore you cannot push a new value, it is not an array

Comment: I need to join the values together in a string.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, something like this:

```
var students = {
   "name":"John", "semester":30
   "name":"Anna", "semester":12

};
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
var students = {
   "name":"Anna", "semester":12
};
```

Because you're effectively updating the `name` and `semester` keys of your object by *declaring* them more than once.

If you need a collection of `name`s and `semester`s values then you're better off with an array based solution. Like this:

```
var students = {
   "name":["John"], "semester":[30]
};
```

And then just access the desired property and `push` values to it. For example:

```
students.name.push("Anna");
students.semester.push(12);
```

If at some point you need your array elements as a single string then just do:

```
students.names.join(',');
students.semester.join(',');
```

This will return your elements in a comma seperated string. If you want something else than a comma between your array elements, just change the `,` in `join` to it.

Note that you could also declare your object as:

```
var students = {
   "name":[], "semester":[]
}
```

If you don't know any value for the keys at the moment of declaration.

Comment: @Light The OP said `push` and `join`. Also, regarding your answer, there are logic errors in your code, plus, the OP certainly didn't said anything about **nested objects**.